# How can I use attributes to run authorization check when method is called?

Tags: c#, aop, custom-attributes

In a C# .NET 4.0 Winforms app I want to use an `AuthorizeActivity` attribute as suggested by [this article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/).

Without using a 3rd party framework, is the following semantics possible?

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    [AuthorizeActivity]
    public void SomeMethodThatRequiresAuthorization()
    {
        // Decide to DoWork or not (maybe throw) based on current user
    }
}
```

I know how to use reflection to get the class, method/attribute, but I'm not sure how to use the attribute to actually run validation code at the time any given user tries to execute this method... I'm thinking I maybe have to "intercept" this method, but I can't find a C# example of how to do this or anything without using a third party framework.

Best I can think of at the moment is to add an `IAuthorizationManager` interface property and then use Reflection to Inject the dependency on startup of my app.

Comment: This will be very complicated.  I don't think implementing it the same as a stateless website is the way to go.

Comment: @ErikPhilips some other suggestion then?

Comment: I try so hard to never tell people to Google, but in this case I would search for `c# winforms user/permission management`.  (Because I've not written any winforms apps with permissions).